# Multiple Auto select certificates for websites using registry

Tags: certificate, registry

I have various websites for which I every day need to reselect a certificate in order to visit the site. Using chrome and edge.
I have made .reg file which works for exactly 1 site. However I am unable to get a working script for multiple websites, with each website having its own certificate.

Working example for 1 website for edge (chrome works too, after changing the path):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\AutoSelectCertificateForUrls]
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteA.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateA\"}}}"
```

Things I have tried:

1. According to various [docs](https://admx.help/?Category=Chrome&Policy=Google.Policies.Chrome::AutoSelectCertificateForUrls), I can specify an array, but I was not able to find an example. So I tried making it in to an string array myself, but this doesn't seem to be the proper format

   ```
    ["{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteA.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateA\"}}}", "{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteB.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateB\"}}}"]
   ```
2. I also tried a REG_MULTI_SZ, which has each pattern on a separate line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it works to define multiple URLs in a single registry entry.
However, for me it worked to create multiple entries and increment the name respectively:

```
"1"="{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteA.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateA\"}}}"
"2"="{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteB.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateB\"}}}"
"3"="{\"pattern\":\"https://websiteC.com",\"filter\":{\"ISSUER\":{\"CN\":\"certificateC\"}}}"
```